# Angular 2 - Image to base64

Tags: javascript, image, angular, base64

For a project I'm working on I need to generate a pdf with the logo of the company. For this, I'm using the jspdf library in Angular 2.

The `addImage()` requires a `base64` string. I'm not quite sure if this is the way to go, but this is my code:

```
let imageURL = 'data:image/png;base64,' + btoa('../../public/img/logo2.png');

this.pdf.addImage(imageURL, 'PNG', 50, 50, 50, 50);
```

This would give the following error:

> Incomplete or corrupt PNG file

When I add `console.log(imageURL)` and I copy the result to the adres bar, instead of the image I'm trying to open a transparant image, like [this example](http://data:image/png;base64,example).

If I drag the image into [this site](https://www.base64-image.de/) and convert the image to a base64 string there, it does give me a working `dataUrl`.

So my essential question is, how can I convert a image to a base64 string, preferably without having to install a library.

Comment: you are base-64 encoding an url, not the image, you need to load it first.

Comment: Like I said, I prefer not having to install a library for this since I'd only need 1 function from the library.

If I absolutely have to, I will do so, but if there is a alternative option I'd love to know

Comment: What are you talking about ? I am not talking about a library... Read the answers of the duplicate !

Comment: the second one (with 413 up) explains very well how to achieve that, and there is no library required...

Comment: Sorry, read the answer in the question wrong. I thought he was talking about `html2canvas` instead of html5's `canvas`

Comment: It worked for me, tx @n00dl3